# Solaris find files within a certain date range containing a duplicate of a certain string

Tags: grep, find, solaris

I'm trying to locate files created within a certain date range that contain the string "field" more than once. 
I've tried using:

```
find messagefolder -mtime -78 -exec egrep -il 'field.*field*' {} \;
```

but its only returning a couple of results.

Comment: `egrep` works one line at a time. If there are two distinct lines with a single `field` each, they won't match. Do you want them to match? Does this explain why you got fewer results than you expected?